# Allowing embed tags but watching for dangerous code in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, embed

I have an option for people to store an embed link to Vimeo or YouTube as part of their profile.  I'm storing it in an `embed_link:string` in my DB.  What do I need to be careful of so people only post those links and not dangerous javascript or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question: [Only Allow Video Embed Codes (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970903/only-allow-video-embed-codes-rails)